# locate the active file in the project explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I noticed that the VS2008 IDE option to "Track Active Item in Project Explorer" only selects the avtive file if the containing project is already expanded.

I could have swon that there was a free utility somewhere locate the active file in the project explorer.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do this using a macro, please see the link below for more information

[Visual Studio Macro: Locate Item in Solution Explorer on Demand](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/visual-studio-macro-track-item-in-solution-explorer-on-demand/)

You can also consider binding a keyboard shortcut to View.TrackActivityInSolutionExplorer for a faster way to turn on or off the built in tracking.